# Runtime access to librarian classes?

Tags: c++, reflection, dll, static-libraries

I have C++ solution with some apps and static libraries:

- UserRace1.exe
- UserRace2.exe
- GreenBody.lib
- BlueBody.lib
- RedBody.lib
- BigWheels.lib
- MiddleWheels.lib
- SmallWheels.lib
- V8Engine.lib
- V12Engine.lib
- RaceTires.lib
- WinterTires.lib
- SimpleTires.lib
- Garage.lib

In application, I just simulate race, one application for each race. Libs consist classes that describe parts of the car (body, wheels, engine, etc.). Every class implement some interface (IBody, IWheels, IEngine, etc.), that described in Garage lib. And Garage.lib should create cars, using parts.

So, I pass car parameters to application, as example: -Car1 -RedBody -MiddleWheels -V8Engine -RaceTires -Car2 -BlueBody -SmallWheels -V12Engine -WinterTires . Application call Garage class: Garage::GetCar(string body, string wheels, string engine, string tires) and garage return Car object, that we use in app. Pay attention, that I pass this arguments like a string. It's important.

Now, about what I want. I write only Garage lib. Other libs will be write by other people. And I want my library has been universal. At this moment, when new part added (e.g. BlackBody.lib) I must add support of this in my Garage.lib. something like:

```
...
else if (body == "RedBody")
{
    car->body = new RedBody();
}
else if (body == "BlackBody")
{
    car->body = new BlackBody();
}
...
```

But I want to get this types dynamicaly. Like:

```
foreach (Librarian lib in Application.GetLibs())
{
    foreach (Type type in lib)
    {
        if (type is IBody)
        {
            if (((IBody)type)::GetColor() == color)
            {
                car->body = type.GetInstance();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if someone add new type, I will not change my library. Problem is, that I write on C++, not C#. And I don't know how to implement it.

Maybe I should use dll instead of static lib? Is this an only way? And if so, whether there would be problems that the applications and dlls use one library (Garage.lib)? Cause they use different runtime libraries (/MT and /MD).

Comment: You can use a factory class for types for each library and you would only need to register the factorys once in the exe.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an entirely "dynamic" solution, using DLLs, provided that:

1. you could derive a Dll name ("BlackBody.dll") from a string '"BlackBody")
2. each Dll exports a factory function, with a predictable name ("Factory", or "BlackBodyFactory")
3. You dynamically load the Dlls, and get the factory pointer function via GetProcAddress
4. your Garage.lib code only knows about the Body base class, because that's what a "body" factory function will return

You should avoid mixing different CRT in the same process. Mixing is possible but involves extra care/work.